# Select value in group based on every/any conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table `entity_translations`, which relate O->M to `string_translations` via `entity_translation_fields`. Each row in `string_translations` has an additional `status` that can be obtained via a join with `current_string_translation_status`.

I need to add an additional column to the result of a select from `entity_translations` that will be determined based on the following conditions:

1. If all `string_translation` records that correspond to an `entity_translation` record have `status` = `'READY'`, then that `entity_translation` gets status `'READY'`.
2. Else, if any `string_translation` records that correspond to an `entity_translation` record have `status` = `'FAILED'`, then that `entity_translation` gets status `'FAILED'`.
3. Else, if any `string_translation` records that correspond to an `entity_translation` record have `status` = `'IN_PROGRESS'`, then that entity translation gets status `'IN_PROGRESS'`.
4. Else, that entity translation gets status `'ADDED'`.

### What I want

Given schema and data in this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/7), I would like to have the following result:

```
|  id | entity_id | entity_type |      status |
| --- | --------- | ----------- | ----------- |
|   1 |         1 |        post |      FAILED | <--- Because status for string translation 2 is "FAILED"
|   2 |         2 |        post | IN_PROGRESS | <--- Because status for string translation 5 is "IN_PROGRESS"
|   3 |         3 |        post |       READY | <--- Because status for string translation 6 is "READY"
```

Here's the query I used to get the data that I would like to aggregate into the above desired result:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `entity_translations`
JOIN `entity_translation_fields`
    ON (`entity_translation_fields`.`entity_translation_id` = `entity_translations`.`id`)
JOIN `string_translations`
    ON (`string_translations`.`id` = `entity_translation_fields`.`string_translation_id`)
JOIN `current_string_translation_status`
    ON (`current_string_translation_status`.`string_translation_id` = `string_translations`.`id`)
ORDER BY `entity_translations`.`id` ASC, `string_translations`.`id` ASC;
```

Markdown tables weren't rendering for some reason, so I just added it as code.

### What I tried

1. One way could be to join `entity_translation` with `string_translation` (and its status view), then group by `entity_translation`'s PK. But I don't know how I could then determine the values from the `status` column that is not in `GROUP BY`. If `ANY()` and `ALL()` were aggregate functions, I could use them in multiple nested `IF` conditions; but they're not.
2. Perhaps, another way is to use a subquery to add a column to `string_translation`. But I don't understand how to then use `ANY` or `ALL` with yet another subquery.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/7) is the whole setup. It has some extra things that are not relevant to this current problem. The query that is relevant is the one that says the following on top:

```
-- Get data for all entity translations, including their current status <----- PROBLEM
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113074/discussion-on-question-by-xedinunknown-select-value-in-group-based-on-every-any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, then

```
SELECT subquery.id, 
       subquery.entity_type, 
       subquery.entity_id,
       CASE WHEN SUM(subquery.status != 'READY') = 0 THEN 'READY'
            WHEN SUM(subquery.status = 'FAILED') > 0 THEN 'FAILED'
            WHEN SUM(subquery.status = 'IN PROGRESS') > 0 THEN 'IN PROGRESS'
            ELSE 'ADDED'
            END status
FROM (SELECT et.id, et.entity_type, et.entity_id, stl.status
      FROM entity_translations et
      JOIN entity_translation_fields etf ON etf.entity_translation_id = et.id
      JOIN string_translations st ON etf.string_translation_id = st.id
      JOIN string_translation_log stl ON stl.string_translation_id = st.id
      JOIN (SELECT string_translation_id, MAX(changed) changed
            FROM string_translation_log
            GROUP BY string_translation_id) stl1 ON stl1.string_translation_id = stl.string_translation_id
                                                AND stl1.changed = stl.changed
      ORDER BY et.id, etf.string_translation_id, stl.changed ) subquery
GROUP BY subquery.id, 
         subquery.entity_type, 
         subquery.entity_id;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/9)

Comment: The result this produces in your fiddle looks correct, thank you very much! However, I'm having trouble understanding
1) Why `SUM()` is used. I don't understand how it works for string values.
2) How I could do the same, but by using the view that aggregates status log entries. Alternatively, why that is not advisable.
3) Why make a subquery for the same table. I tried doing it without the subquery, and got correct results.

Comment: Here's what my setup looks right now, and it seems to be working correctly: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFQtPUnQsJc4cPWb4tGoyQ/10

Comment: @XedinUnknown, `CASE WHEN SUM(subquery.status != 'READY') ...` is the same as: `SUM(CASE WHEN subquery.status != 'READY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...`. MySQL has a somewhat liberal attitude when it comes to implicit casting.

Comment: *I don't understand how it works for string values.* Argument of SUM() function is comparing expression which have not string but integer (formally boolean but MySQL have no such datatype). Integer may be summarized easily. * I tried doing it without the subquery, and got correct results.* This is random - without it a random row from a group will be used whereas subquery guarantees that the row with maximal datetime will be taken. Execute the subquery only and investigate the output, do the same with subquery and the table itself only.

Comment: If `SUM(CASE WHEN)` is same as `CASE WHEN SUM()`, then I understand: it's implicitly transforming `bool` to `int`, and adding them together.

About subquery, I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @XedinUnknown *If SUM(CASE WHEN) is same as CASE WHEN SUM()* o_O NEVER!

Comment: Thought that's what you wrote. But now I understand, having looked again: the expression `subquery.status != 'READY` evaluates to bool, and that is implicitly cast to int, which are then added. Gotcha! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By the way, I'm not using your join per se. I'm using my view. That's likely why it works: the view already guarantees that the last status is taken. Not sure why you didn't use that view.

Comment: @XedinUnknown *I'm not using your join per se. I'm using my view.* This may decrease the query performance. And cannot increase it.

Comment: Really? I'm not an expert, but a view sounds much more optimizable than a subquery, because it is a separate component that can be cached/indexed/etc separately.

Comment: @XedinUnknown *Really?* 100%. Even 101%. *it is a separate component that can be cached/indexed/etc separately.* Yes - it can be materialized (cached to disk) which is extremely expensive operation.

Comment: Caching exists because it's faster.

Comment: @XedinUnknown *Caching exists because it's faster.* This is common error. Caching **in memory** is faster. Caching on disk is very-very slow. On version 5.6 the view is cached on disk very often, close to always.

Comment: Caching that is slower kinda defeats the point of caching. Don't you think?

Comment: @XedinUnknown Caching in memory needs memory (strange, is it?) which' available amount is always low. If server cannot allocate memory amount which is enough for caching (or it decides that it is not safe for concurrent threads and/or overall performance) then intermediate rowset will be cached on disk. This is a norma. For view rowsets this on-disk caching is applied close to always.

Comment: Sure. But think about this: tables are stored on disk. Indexes are stored on disk. When we query stuff, we query from disk (unless maybe running the same query again, etc). And everything runs normally. Why would querying a view that is on disk be more expensive?

Comment: @XedinUnknown Because reading tables/indices from disk must be performed ANYCASE (if they're not cached). In a view used query the intermediate view rowset is saved and is then readed (if it was eliminated from the cache) ADDITIONALLY.

Comment: That doesn't look like a problem at all, because this just means that the view will act like any other table. I think I'm OK with giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what @Akina has explained to me, here is my version, which I prefer, because it uses an already existing view, keeping that logic centralized, and making the eventual query simpler. There are also a little more fields, because I eventually needed them. They can be removed from `SELECT`, in which case they also have to be removed from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Disclaimer: Of course, without the answer of @Akina, I wouldn't be able to figure it out. I'm just adding mine here to show perhaps a different approach. I am a software engineer, an architect; not a DBA.

```sql
SELECT
    `et`.`id`,
    `et`.`entity_type`,
    `et`.`entity_id`,
    `et`.`source_lang`,
    `et`.`destination_lang`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(`csts`.`status` != 'READY') = 0 THEN 'READY'
         WHEN SUM(`csts`.`status` = 'FAILED') > 0 THEN 'FAILED'
         WHEN SUM(`csts`.`status` = 'IN_PROGRESS') > 0 THEN 'IN_PROGRESS'
         ELSE 'ADDED'
         END status
FROM `entity_translations` `et`
JOIN `entity_translation_fields` `etf`
    ON (`etf`.`entity_translation_id` = `et`.`id`)
JOIN `string_translations` `st`
    ON (`st`.`id` = `etf`.`string_translation_id`)
JOIN `current_string_translation_status` `csts`
    ON (`csts`.`string_translation_id` = `st`.`id`)
GROUP BY `et`.`id`, `et`.`entity_type`, `et`.`entity_id`, `et`.`source_lang`, `et`.`destination_lang`;
```